# Is there a way to access blob storage from specific networks without authentication

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to access different azure blob storages from an azure service which is connected to a network. I have added the service's network to all storage accounts. When requests to a storage are authenticated via a connection string all works well but it is impossible to know to which storage is each file and use the correct credentials. Also, some packages read the credentials from an environment variable, which makes it impossible to use many storages.

So, I am looking for a way to access the storage accounts without authentications, as if the storage allowed public access only to specific networks.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can access anonymously to specifics URL, you cannot enumerate the content
[image]

If you require anonymous access, you can do the following:

1. In the network section of your storage account limited the connections to certain Virtual Networks and Public IPs
   [image]
2. in your container you must change the access level to any with anonymous read access.
   [image]

After that, you can access the URL of the files anonymously for the selected virtual networks and Public IPs

Hope this helps!